# Magento, access functions in Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Im new to Magento

Just installed this plugin http://shop.bubblecode.net/magento-attribute-image.html
All is going well, so on my product view page I run the following code to get my attribute ids

```
$ids = $_product->getData('headset_features');
```

Now the above plugin states it comes with this helper http://shop.bubblecode.net/attachment/download/link/id/11/

The function in this class I need to use is

```
 public function getAttributeOptionImage($optionId)
{
    $images = $this->getAttributeOptionImages();
    $image = array_key_exists($optionId, $images) ? $images[$optionId] : '';
    if ($image && (strpos($image, 'http') !== 0)) {
        $image = Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl($image);
    }

    return $image;
}
```

I am really struggling to make use of this function.
 I noticed in the helper `class Bubble_AttributeOptionPro_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract`

So here is what I thought should work

```
echo Mage::helper('core')->Bubble_AttributeOptionPro_Helper_Data->getAttributeOptionImage($ids[0]);
```

But its not working for me, it kills the page, can someone please tell me how to access the function.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

Just tried `$helper = Mage::helper('AttributeOptionPro');` which also kills the page

Comment: Why would you think that `Mage::helper('core')->Bubble_AttributeOptionPro_Helper_Data->getAttributeOptionImage($ids[0])` would work?

Comment: Because Bubble_AttributeOptionPro_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract so I assumed that helper was the core. As said in post im new to magento.

Comment: Ok, I see now. What you are doing though is not going to work regardless of the framework being used - it's invalid PHP syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the helper classgroup for this module (`bubble_aop`, [defined in the config](http://shop.bubblecode.net/attachment/download/link/id/10/)), you can instantiate the helper class as follows:

```
$helper = Mage::helper('bubble_aop');
```

However I do not see anything in the class definition which gets it to pull data from the product entity.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into the module's etc folder and in config.xml you should have a node called helpers under config > global. The first child of that node (so that is before class node) is the name you should use to instantiate your helper and call your method so you would have something like Mage::helper('child_node_name')->getAttributeOptionImage($optionId);
Most of the helper classes extend Mage_Core_Helper_Abstrat which is abstract (can't be instantiated). If you run get_class(Mage::helper('core')) you will get Mage_Core_Helper_Data, because actually the default helper class in a module is Namespace/Module/Hepler/Data.php